# Restoring mysqldump backup with TYPE='MYISAM'

Tags: sql, mysql

```
-- MySQL dump 9.11
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: Books
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   4.0.20a-debug

--
-- Table structure for table `BX-Users`
--

CREATE TABLE `BX-Users` (
  `User-ID` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `Location` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `Age` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`User-ID`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;

--
```

This is the view if the dump file that i want to restore. I used the command

C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin>mysql -h localhost -u medha -p Books < BX-User
s.sql

it returns an error saying

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 11: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the m
anual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 6

Please suggest. I also tried entering the user in specified database and then using source command to restore it .. doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace TYPE=MyISAM with ENGINE=MyISAM

I tested it and it worked. :)